# Laravel str_random() or custom function?

Tags: string, function, random, laravel, uuid

Is the Laravel str_random() function random enough so that I can use it for IDs?

For example:

```
str_random(32);
```

This produces a random string of length 32 made up of alphanumeric characters [a-zA-z0-9] (62 characters in total).

Which equates to 2272657884496751345355241563627544170162852933518655225856 possibilities.

However, my question is, is this going to be good enough? Or should I consider using UUIDs or another custom function.

Comment: You could always check to make sure it's not a duplicate before saving it, like when generating unique slugs. Of course, that's very unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`str_random` (`Str::random()`) tries to use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` which is a pseudo random number generator optimized for cryptography, not uniqueness. If `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is not available, it falls back to `quickRandom()`:

```
public static function quickRandom($length = 16)
{
    $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, 5)), 0, $length);
}
```

In my opinion `quickRandom` code **is not** reliable for uniqueness nor cryptography.

Yes, having `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` and using 32 bytes is almost impossible to see a collision, but it's still possible. If you want to make sure your strings/numbers will be unique (99.99%), you better use a UUID function. This is what I normally use:

```
/**
 * 
 * Generate v4 UUID
 * 
 * Version 4 UUIDs are pseudo-random.
 */
public static function v4() 
{
    return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',

    // 32 bits for "time_low"
    mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

    // 16 bits for "time_mid"
    mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

    // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
    // four most significant bits holds version number 4
    mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,

    // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
    // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
    // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
    mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,

    // 48 bits for "node"
    mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
    );
}
```

It generates a VALID RFC 4211 COMPLIANT version 4 UUID.

Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions

Comment: Where you state 'if it is available' with respect to openssl, why wouldn't it be? Also, what is the best method for uniqueness as I will be using the strings as IDs.

Comment: In this line: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L190, Taylor check if it's available, so I have to presume it might not always be.

Comment: In your opinion, would quickRandom suffice? if I were to check that it is of course unique before I save it. Chances of two collisions occurring consecutively are very slim...?

Comment: It's not. It may be good for temporary file creation/deletion, or to provide html unique id on pages, to give some examples, but not to be used as id. Edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Just to be sure then, is it ok to use UUID as an ID within a database rather than a standard auto-incrementing integer?

Comment: There's no 100% safety in this case, I think it's very safe but I would still try catch (the save(), create() or update()) and generate a new UUID in case of collision.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into implementing the UUID as ID, also adding try-catch when dealing with the DB.

Comment: There was [a bug in PHP implementation of OpenSSL](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70014) giving tons of collisions which is fixed in the following versions: >= 5.4.44, >= 5.5.28, >= 5.6.13, >= 7.0.0

Comment: For your UUID, all you're doing is generating a really long random number based entirely off `mt_rand()`. It'd be no different from doing `mt_rand($largeNumber, $largerNumber)`... you're just adding some dashes to make it look less like a really long number.

Answer (score 72):

you can use this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$random = Str::random(40);
```

Comment: which was worked on laravel 8. you are welcome

Answer (score 11):

**The accepted answer was true in April of 2014. It is not accurate anymore.** In November of 2014 [there was a commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/46c1a7be25057a174a8d7cacc7b1e0e51a5f935a#diff-d19e1b0b8c742f268aabdbf1595bcfbd) which removed the use of `quickRandom`. As [`random_bytes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) became available in PHP 7 Laravel slowly shifted to that function and uses that one only without any fallback.

[`ramsey/uuid`](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) is the default UUID library in Laravel. By looking at the code we can find out the default random generator is `RandomBytesGenerator` which uses `random_bytes`. The same method `Str::random` uses.

The Wikipedia page about UUID states the following about UUID v4:

> [...] version-4 UUID will have 6 predetermined variant and version bits, leaving 122 bits for the randomly generated part, [...]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)

128 bits = 122 random bits + 6 version bits. 128 bits is exactly 16 bytes. Most of the UUID implementations reads 16 bytes of random bytes and then replaces the version at the specified position (in case of v4).

All in all, as of now it is almost the same if you would use `Str::random` with length equal to 16 or `Uuid::uuid4` (without modifying the `randomGenerator` of `Uuid`).

Answer (score 3):

To make it more unique use TIMESTAMP and concat row id with it simple and zero possibility to repeat number

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) package.

For example:

```
Uuid::generate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 6 version, on that Illuminate\Support\Str::random works well however neither str_random nor Illuminate\Support\Str::str_random works for me using Laravel 6.

Bellow you can see the function's documentation

```
/**
* Generate a more truly "random" alpha-numeric string.
*
* @param  int  $length
* @return string
*/
public static function random($length = 16)
```

Answer (score -1):

the easier one is:

```
$random = str_random(3).substr(time(), 6,8).str_random(3);
```

It will generate a 10 digit true unique number.

Comment: It does not generate a number, but a string with number and letters, and using time is not very secure, function like random_bytes is safer

Comment: @LK77 It'll generate alpha numeric unique code with zero duplication possibility.

Comment: yeah but i can generate in advance every possible value, so better using uuid then