# Does bcrypt + str_random generate a secure password?

Tags: php, security, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am creating random passwords for first time users of my application.

Is `$password = bcrypt(str_random(12));` a cryptographically secure way to generate a password in Laravel 5.1?

I can see from this answer: [Laravel str_random() or custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015874/laravel-str-random-or-custom-function) that `str_random()` is not sufficient. Does wrapping it in `bcrypt()` help?

Also, are there universal or generally accepted standards for password generation security?

Comment: Generating a password for someone else and then (probably) somehow sending it is insecure per definition and in practice. Instead you should _not_ generate a password or at least not send and use it at all. You should offer a link where people can trigger a password reset email message to their registered address. That link, based on a one time token, should be usable only for a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

For standard uses it should be fine. The bigger problem is that you will send/show the password to user. Normally the password should be written by user in password filed (with ***), then hashed and saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$password = str_random(12);`

Under the hood, it tries to use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or `quickRandom` (see [Laravel str_random() or custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015874/laravel-str-random-or-custom-function)).

You will generate very difficult to guess passwords. Much more difficult to guess than what your actual users will choose (password1234).

The link you provided talks about other properties that make the function not suitable for unique user ID generation.

Also using bcrypt does not add any more entropy to the password. I knew your password generation function had a vulnerability that allows me to guess its output, then all I need to do is bcrypt that output. The point being that for this specific use case, bcrypt doesn't add value.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate secure, random passwords in Laravel 10 and newer like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
$password = Str::password();
// 'EbJo2vE-AS:U,$%_gkrV4n,q~1xy/-_4'

$password = Str::password(12); 
// 'qwuar>#V|i]N'
```