# Laravel Upload Image and Generate Random ID as name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Whats the best way to generate and random ID number for every image where i want upload in Laravel 5?

My Upload:

```
<input type="file" id="mypicture" name="mypicture">
```

Controller:

```
public function MyPicture(Request $request){
  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->mypicture= $request->mypicture;
  $user->save();
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

Thats the way i do it always for other things:

```
->uniqueid = 'VA'.str_random(28);
```

how can i add it to my Controller for image name?
And how can i use only alphabetic character not numbers? Or i must change my DB Table.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function MyPicture(Request $request){
  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->mypicture = date('mdYHis') . uniqid() . $request->mypicture;
  $user->save();
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

You can use Date (Y-m-d H:i:s) and `uniqid()` to generate unique name every file.

Comment: I get as result "012320180639085a66ca7ca54d56_icon-icons.com_68891.png" from "icon-icons.com_68891.png" now but the image dont upload and i cant find it on my Server why?

Comment: Have you added `file => true` in your `<form>` ? Also enable file upload in  your php.ini by doing: `file_uploads = On` Along with that, PHP has a file upload limit of 2 MB, so even if you enable file upload, you have to increase upload limit in php.ini.

Comment: What you mean? Its the first time i hear from this

Comment: You `<form>` should be like: `{{!! Form::open(['route' => 'your-route-name', 'class' => 'if-any', 'files' => true]) !!}} `

Comment: in Laravel 5? i dont have like this in my script

Comment: or must I also now set the $path?

Comment: So, what does your form tag looks like? Even if you use basic `<form></form>`, then you've to do something like: `<form action="your-route" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Okay i have tried with files true but also no results. My default Image folder is /img/imagename...... i get in my DB the generated name but the image not saved in an folder from me....

Comment: Do you have write permission on the folder where you're saving your image? Along with that, just below your `MyPicture()`, add this code: `print_r(\Input::all()); exit;` and add that output in your question.

Comment: Oh shit i have forget the code for upload Image. I have try it always with saved images in this folder! Many Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

use [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

```
if (Input::hasFile('mypicture')) {
     $mypicture = Input::file('mypicture');
     $user->mypicture= uniqid().$mypicture->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the same here:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->mypicture = $request->mypicture;
$user->filename = str_random(28);
$user->save();

$request->mypicture->storeAs('images', $user->filename);
```

If you want to use only letters, use one of [the existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23016381/1227923).

Comment: But i have 2 Images in my "<form class="" action="....." method="post">". Cant i just set it behind in my Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has an inbuilt method for this, using their File facade.

From laravel docs:

```
    $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');

    return $path;
```

By default, the store method will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name. The path to the file will be returned by the store method so you can store the path, including the generated file name, in your database.

Comment: Suppose that I have two folders. Will the filename be unique in each folder or in both folders?